# Kendo filter selector bug in IE10

Tags: kendo-ui, internet-explorer-10, kendo-grid

Using the Kendo UI filters to sort a grid by status the dropdown options cannot be hovered in IE10. When you hover the options they collapse and revert as if mouseout action. This only happens in IE10 - see screencast http://screencast.com/t/OzRveEDM

Answer (score 0):

We had something very similar happening in our application.  The drop down would hide itself in IE.

For us, the container the drop down was in had a 'mouseleave' event tied to it, which was meant to hide the container.  I suspect you may have something similar based on your Jing.  I would check if the container created when you click 'Filter' has a mouseleave event on it.